# Proper way to execute ProcessingPools in sequence

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am using the pathos.multiprocessing library (since my worker methods have lambdas in them), and am trying to run two ProcessingPools in sequence.

For example:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
pool=ProcessingPool(nodes=2)
res=pool.map(workerFunc,workerArgList)
pool.close()
pool.join()
# ...
pool=ProcessingPool(nodes=2)
res=pool.map(workerFunc2,workerArgList2)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The code, as is, returns an AssertionError in pool.py's map() function at the 2nd pool.map() (at assert self._state == RUN). Each pool works fine independently. It appears that, for some reason, the pool's state is set to TERMINATE instead of RUN in the 2nd initialization. How should I initialize the 2nd pool (or terminate the first) to get the desired behavior? Or is this some sort of bug I have stumbled upon?

Thank you!
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official Python Documentation on Pool.map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map),

> It blocks until the result is ready.

In other words, `pool.map()` won't return the result until all processing is finished. When using `pool.map()` you don't need to run `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` every time, just do it once after you're done using `pool`.

Comment: Thank you Vito. It was quite some time since I needed this, so I found a different solution. I don't think this explains the AssertionError, since the first pool runs and closes successfully, but I will try to make a simple example to verify.